# Word for to look at someone telling them to shut up

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word in which you look at someone with your eyes such that you're telling them to remain quiet.

For example, you are in a serious situation and your friend tries to make a joke and you look at him with wide eyes, telling him to just shut up.

Is there a word for that?

Also can you guide me to a site where words for different expressions are given?

Comment: 'She silenced him with a stare' is typically used (when it actually works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's **quell**:

> 1. Put an end to (a rebellion or other disorder), typically by the use of force.
>      *"extra police were called to quell the disturbance"*
>
>    - **subdue or silence (someone).**
>        *"Connor quelled him with a look"*

It's often used in this context - you would give someone a 'quelling look' which would be the kind that silently tells them to stop what they are doing.

Comment: Don't know the reason for the downvote, but, +1.